# An inequality with $a_n=\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt{2x}}}}_{n \text { times}}}$

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Let the sequence $(a_n)_n$ defined by $$a_n=\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt{2x}}}}_{n \text { times}}}$$

1)Prove that $$\frac12 \leq a_n \leq \frac{1}{\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots+\sqrt{2}}}}_{n-1 \text { times}}} \; \forall n\geq 1$$

2)Find the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_n$

If I could find a closed form of the first integral the problem would be quite easier, so is there a simplification possible for these iterated roots?

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 + ... +\sqrt{2}}} \to 2$ as $n \to \infty$, this can be seen by constructing the sequence $x_n = \sqrt{2 + x_{n-1}}$ and setting $x_0 = \sqrt{2}$.

The inequalities, then, follow by the fact that the integrand is decreasing on $[0,1]$ along with the identity above.

1) $a_n \geq 1/2$:

let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 + ... +\sqrt{2x}}}}$ then $f_n(x)$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ and $a_n = \int_0^1 f_n(x) dx \geq \int_0^1 f_n(1) dx \geq 1/2$. as needed since $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 + ... +\sqrt{2}}} \leq 2$ this inequality can be seen by my construction since the sequence $x_n$ above is monotonic and bounded.

Comment: why the down vote, the solution is terse but correct.

Comment: What about when $n$ is small?

Comment: $n$ starts at $1$ so it can't be that small

Comment: I think you proved it for $n \to \infty$ not $\forall n \geq 1$

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let $${{c}_{n}}=\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots +\sqrt{2}}}}_{n\ \text{times}},$$ and clearly we have $0<c_1<c_2<\cdots <c_n<\cdots <2$.
Note that the integrand is monotonically decreasing. Hence, $$\frac{1}{{c_n}}\le a_n\le \frac{1}{{c_{n-1}}}.$$
Then assertion 1) is proved, and 2) follows from 1) since $\lim_{x\to \infty}c_n = 2$.